# Limit of a function with two variables and discontinuity

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Prove that the following limit exists and is zero:

$$\lim_{x \to 0, y \to 0} \frac{xy-x^3}{x^2+y^2}$$

I am trying to apply an epsilon delta proof of the limit. However, I am having trouble working through it.

Comment: The limit as written isn't 0.  When $y=x$, for example, the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 3):

Using polar coordinates: $\;x=r\cos\theta\;,\;\;y=r\sin\theta\;$ , you get

$$\frac{\left(\cos\theta\sin\theta-r\cos^3\theta\right)}{1}\xrightarrow[r\to0]{}\cos\theta\sin\theta$$

and thus the limit depends on the path chosen (i.e., it depends on the angle $\;\theta\;$ ), so the limit doesn't exist